# Callout using Apex Trigger when custom field updated

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-experience, callout

I would like to create a callout (webhook) when a custom field `Batch_Name__c` is updated which belongs to the Account Object.

The purpose of this callout is to send all account information to an external webhook (automation tool with no integration) only when the custom field is modified. (to reduce the number of calls and improve performances)

Using https://salesforce-webhook-creator.herokuapp.com/app, I created the following Apex Trigger (string url is changed)

```
trigger AccountTriggerWebhookTrigger on Account (after update) {

    String url = 'https://xxxxxxxx/AccountTrigger';

    String content = Webhook.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);

    Webhook.callout(url, content);

}
```

This trigger the external webhook well but in large volume so it's not scalable.

My knowledge in APEX is quite low and thats the first time I'm trying to use it (in a sandbox environment for now).
If i'm right, it's possible to include a data filter based on the custom field `batch_name__c`.

I don't know how hard nor stable this usecase is so I would be glad to get some feedback from you all :)

Thanks a lot for reading me and for your assistance.

Comment: Instead of writing a trigger in Apex, build a [record-triggered Flow](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/winter-21-release-highlights-no-code/get-hands-on-with-a-record-triggered-flow) - it will do what you're after via a no-code approach. You will need to wrap your webhook in an [invocable action](https://unofficialsf.com/understanding-invocable-actions/) and call it from the Flow.

Comment: Thanks @identigral I will deep dive into it, seems to be a more appropriate approach according my Apex skills.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post a separate question instead of combining multiple questions into one or using comments for a discussion. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @identigral will do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the following

- Trigger all starting conditions ideally from a Record Triggered Flow
  -Whenever apply on flow , call to an specific apex method, by calling a method with @InvocableMethod data-annotation (you can have just one method with this notation per class, public static void method I believe)
- Then do the callout from that invocableMethod.
- Additionally, if you take the response and needs to DML on records, you will have to additionally, workaround by using futureMethod from the invocableMethod

If you are concern about volume, concurrency, probable working with Queueable classes may help.

you can ask queued job or tracking on an object if you want to calculate numbers of http request you are doing, consider to revisit salesforce limits and allocations

[Salesforce apex_callouts_timeouts link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm)